# Nextjs: avoid infinite loop when adding a conditional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js application with the following page:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

import NotFound from '@/pages';
import { Page, PostBlock } from '@/components';

const Main = ({ router }) => {
  const [postsData, setPostsData] = useState({ posts: [], page: 0, pages: 0 });

  function fetchData() {
    axios
      .get('/api/articles', {
        params: {
          page: router.query?.page,
          lang: router.locale,
          tag: router.query.tag,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        setPostsData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // if (!postsData.posts.length) return <NotFound />;

  return (
    <Page title='Home' className='home-template'>
      <div id='grid' className='post-grid'>
        {postsData.posts?.map(post => {
          return (
            <PostBlock
              featured={post.featured}
              key={post.key}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Main);
```

The api fetches some articles on component mount, and display them in the UI. So far so good.

I also want to display a component in case there are no articles to display or if the api fails, but if I uncomment the line

`if (!postsData.posts.length) return <NotFound />;`

the application ends up in an infinite loop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where does it loop? Does it fetch the data multiple times?

Comment: setPostsData(response.data); this is creating new object with response coming from api. In case if there are no posts, is the api response coming as empty array. If the posts value is not matching with array format then it is possible to throw a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting posts as empty array in case if the data is empty

```
if (!(postsData.posts||[]).length) return <NotFound />;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to conditional render your loop part like below:

```
 return (
    <Page title='Home' className='home-template'>
      <div id='grid' className='post-grid'>
        {
          (postsData?.posts||[]).length ?  
            <>
              {postsData.posts.map(post => {
                 return (
                    <PostBlock
                     featured={post.featured}
                     key={post.key}
                    />
                  );
                })
              }
            </> : <NotFound />
         }            
      </div>
    </Page>
  );
```